# Why __PHP_Incomplete_Class?

Tags: php

I am developing a web application in PHP and MySQL.

I get some data from the database and set it into a PHP Object. When I do a var_dump() of the variable that contains the information, I see this:

```
    object(__PHP_Incomplete_Class)[2]
   public '__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name' => string 'Empresa' (length=7)
   public 'IDEmpresa' => string '13' (length=2)
   public 'Nombre' => string 'Prueba' (length=6)
   ... other attributes
```

Why the object is "__PHP_Incomplete_Class" and what are the implications of this?

Thanks!

Comment: You'd normally expect to see this if you were unserializing a serialized object and the class hasn't yet been loaded into your script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that you've unserialized (presumably from the session) an object whose class is not defined in current runtime.