# How do I properly load the definition or serialize an instance/object of a PHP class when storing?

Tags: php, api, serialization, ads, google-ads-api

I'm using the Google Ads (formerly Adwords) PHP library to manage clients' accounts, and it's running on PHP 7.

I got the examples working, but I am having trouble storing, as a $_SESSION variable or otherwise, the created OAuth2 object instance of the OAuth2 class without getting [this __PHP_Incomplete_Class error](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php).

I know I have to properly serialize or define it somehow before storing, but I'm a noob at PHP, backend coding, and internet security. I've found similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10069120/session-php-incomplete-class) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45455299/php-serialize-object-tree). Also, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23792907/why-php-incomplete-class) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6574984/php-problem-with-php-incomplete-class) their responses were:

> It means that you've unserialized (presumably from the session) an
>   object whose class is not defined in current runtime

and that the "class definition had not been loaded", but I don't know exactly how to do this. Could I somehow use [var_dump](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) to do this? I'm at my wit's end now. Specifically I'm wanting to properly store the [$oauth2 object](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#offline) so that I can use it to make calls using the client library.

```
$oauth2->setCode($_GET['code']);
$authToken = $oauth2->fetchAuthToken();
```

Comment: You need to include the PHP file that contains the class declaration. Such libraries usually come with an autoloader component, that can handle this automatically, so that you only have to include the one autoloader file, and it will take care of including class files as necessary for you - check if that’s the case with the one you are using as well.

Comment: I already have "use Google\Auth\OAuth2;", so you're saying have "include Google\Auth\OAuth2;" as well?

Comment: Yes you do; `use` only declares a _namespace_, but does not embed the actual code of any class.